# Visual Studio 2017 - adding new WCF service adds the interface and throws object reference error

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I click right button of mouse and choose "Add new item". I choose WCF from the dialog. Visual studio adds the interface and throws an

> Object reference error

After clicking ok, VS opens the new item dialog to add a new item.

Why can't I add a WCF service, without an error?

Comment: If this is a bug report, I'm innocent: what *is* your question?

Answer (score 0):

system.servicemodel reference was missing.

adding a reference to system.servicemodel and then adding the wcf service, solved the problem.